# VS Code is not taking multiple inputs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This code is only getting the age input. It is not getting name input.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "You are "<<age<<" years old"<<endl; 
    cout << "Enter your name: "<<endl; 
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Hello, "<<name;
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to get age and name as inputs and tried to store them in their respective variables. I am not able to get both these inputs. Even if I change the order of the code, I am able to get only one input.

Answer (score 0):

You need correction in the code as below

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: "; 
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "You are "<<age<<" years old"<<endl; 
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<<"Hello, "<<name;
    return 0;
}
```